# Trouble setting up a Transparent TCP Proxy on Android/Linux

Tags: java, android, linux, proxy, iptables

I am trying to set up a transparent TCP proxy on Android for my dissertation, but am having some issues. I am using software that I found on this site - http://en.dfr.ch/free-software/java-tcp-proxy - the source is freely available.

I have extracted the source and created an Android application from it. The main bulk of the code is in the below loop.

```
while(!interrupted()) {
    Socket serverSocket=srvSock.accept();
    Log.e(TAG, "New incoming connection");
    try {
        serverSocket.setSoLinger(true,lingerTime);
        Socket clientSocket=new Socket(dstAddr,dstPort);
        clientSocket.setSoLinger(true,lingerTime);
        Log.e(TAG, "Server socket and client socket created");
        StreamCopyThread sToC=new StreamCopyThread(serverSocket,clientSocket, "BrowserSide");
        StreamCopyThread cToS=new StreamCopyThread(clientSocket,serverSocket, "ServerSide");
        Log.e(TAG, "Working threads created");
        sToC.setPeer(cToS);
        cToS.setPeer(sToC);
        Log.e(TAG, "Peers defined");
        synchronized(lock) {
            connections.addElement(cToS);
            connections.addElement(sToC);
            sToC.start();
            cToS.start();
            Log.e(TAG, "Working threads running");
        }
    } catch(Exception xc) {
        Log.e(TAG, header+":"+xc.getMessage());
        // xc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
srvSock.close();
```

Traffic is redirected from an IP to localhost where the proxy handles it. To do the redirect, I have used the following iptables rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -d [any ip] -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

This seems to work in redirecting the traffic, however when the proxy is running, it seems to continuously creates new threads (connections) until it runs out of memory. With the logging, the output it similar to below. Where ... represents several loops of the above output logging before the error.

> Working threads running
>
> New incoming connection
>
> Server socket and client socket created
>
> Working threads created
>
> Peers defined
>
> BrowserSide-->611
>
> Working threads running
>
> ...
>
> /127.0.0.1:8080 <-> /[any ip]:80:Too many open files

I am really confused as to why it's not working properly. The same error appears when I try it in Ubuntu on a computer, but it works perfectly fine in Windows. I am thinking it may be an issue with iptables or some jvm/socket based issues in Linux. I am currently running iptables version 1.4.4.

Thank you in advance for taking your time to have a look at this problem.

Comment: Don't mess around with SO_LINGER. It's pointless, especially in Java because you don't get an error if the close times out. `serverSocket` is a terrible name for an accepted socket, especially when it is accepted from an object whose class name is `ServerSocket`.

Answer (score 1):

You are more than likely initiating a connection in your code to the same port that is being redirected.

Consider:

```
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -d [any ip] -m owner \! --gid-owner proxyrunner -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

This will exclude programs running as group `proxyrunner`, make sure to execute your proxy accordingly:

```
sg proxyrunner 'java [...]'
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to run other Java proxies such as Little proxy with the same configuration?

http://dev.littleshoot.org/littleproxy/

Other open source proxies: http://proxies.xhaus.com/java/

Comment: Doesn't even attempt to answer the actual question.